# SVM: problems with SMO algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I'm currently trying to code a non linear SVM for handwritten digits recognition using the MNIST data base.

I chose to use the SMO algorithm (based on Platt's paper and other books), but I have some trouble implementing it.

When I run the code over the training set, the bias goes higher and higher, sometimes until "Inf" value, leading the SVM to "classify" every example in the same class.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy
import gzip
import struct
import matplotlib
from sklearn import datasets
from copy import copy

class SVM:

    def __init__(self, constant, data_set, label_set):
        self._N = len(data_set)
        if self._N != len(label_set):
            raise Exception("Data size and label size don't match.")


        self._C = constant
        self._epsilon = 0.001
        self._tol = 0.001

        self._data = [numpy.ndarray.flatten((1/255)*elt) for elt in data_set]
        self._dimension = len(self._data[0])
        self._label = label_set
        self._alphas = numpy.zeros((1, self._N))
        self._b = 0
        self._errors = numpy.ndarray((2, 0))







    def kernel(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = x1.reshape(1,self._dimension)
        result = numpy.power(numpy.dot(x1, x2), 3)

        return result






    def evaluate(self, x):
        result = 0
        i = 0
        while i < self._N:
            result +=  self._alphas[0, i]*self._label[i]*self.kernel(x, self._data[i])
            i += 1

        result += self._b       
        return result






    def update(self, i1, i2, E2):
        i1 = int(i1)
        i2 = int(i2)
        if i1 == i2:
            return 0

        y1 = self._label[i1]
        y2 = self._label[i2]
        alpha1 = self._alphas[0, i1]
        alpha2 = self._alphas[0, i2]

        #If alpha1 is non-bound, its error is in the cache.
        #So we check its position to extract its error.
        #Else, we compute it.
        if alpha1 > 0 and alpha1 < self._C :
            position = 0
            for i, elt in enumerate(self._errors[0, :]):
                if elt == i1:
                    position = i

            E1 = self._errors[1, position]
        else:
            E1 = self.evaluate(self._data[i1]) - y1


        s = y1*y2
        H = L = 0

        if y1 != y2:
            L = max(0, alpha2 - alpha1)
            H = min(self._C, self._C + alpha2 - alpha1)
        else:
            L = max(0, alpha2 + alpha1 - self._C)
            H = min(self._C, alpha2 + alpha1)


        if H == L:
            return 0

        K11 = self.kernel(self._data[i1], self._data[i1])
        K12 = self.kernel(self._data[i1], self._data[i2])
        K22 = self.kernel(self._data[i2], self._data[i2])

        eta = K11 + K22 - 2*K12
        if eta > 0:
            alpha2_new = alpha2 + (y2*(E1 - E2)/eta)
            if alpha2_new < L:
                alpha2_new = L
            elif alpha2_new > H:
                alpha2_new = H

        else:
            f1 = y1*(E1 + self._b) - alpha1*K11 - s*alpha2*K12
            f2 = y2*(E2 + self._b) - alpha2*K22 - s*alpha1*K12

            L1 = alpha1 + s*(alpha2 - L)
            H1 = alpha1 + s*(alpha2 - H)

            FuncL = L1*f1 + L*f2 + (1/2)*numpy.square(L1)*K11 + (1/2)*numpy.square(L)*K22 + s*L1*L*K12
            FuncH = H1*f1 + H*f2 + (1/2)*numpy.square(H1)*K11 + (1/2)*numpy.square(H)*K22 + s*H1*H*K12

            if FuncL < FuncH - self._epsilon:
                alpha2_new = L
            elif FuncL > FuncH + self._epsilon:
                alpha2_new = H
            else:
                alpha2_new = alpha2



        if numpy.abs(alpha2_new - alpha2) < self._epsilon*(alpha2_new+alpha2+ self._epsilon):
            return 0

        alpha1_new = alpha1 + s*(alpha2 - alpha2_new)

        #Update of the threshold.
        b1 = E1 + y1*(alpha1_new - alpha1)*K11 + y2*(alpha2_new - alpha2)*K12 + self._b
        b2 = E2 + y1*(alpha1_new - alpha1)*K12 + y2*(alpha2_new - alpha2)*K22 + self._b

        if L < alpha1_new < H:
            b_new = b1
        elif L < alpha2_new < H:
            b_new = b2
        else:
            b_new = (b1+b2)/2


#Update the cache error

        #If alpha2 was bound and its new value is non-bound, we add its index and its error to the cache.
        #If alpha2 was unbound and its new value is bound, we delete it from the cache.
        if (alpha2 == 0 or alpha2 == self._C) and (alpha2_new > 0 and alpha2_new < self._C):
            vector_alpha2_new = numpy.array([i2, E2])
            vector_alpha2_new = vector_alpha2_new.reshape((2, 1))
            self._errors = numpy.concatenate((self._errors, vector_alpha2_new), 1)


        if (alpha2 > 0 and alpha2 < self._C) and (alpha2_new == 0 or alpha2_new == self._C):
            l = 0
            position = 0
            while l < len(self._errors[0, :]):
                if self._errors[0, l] == i2:
                    position = l
                l += 1

            self._errors = numpy.delete(self._errors, position, 1)


        #We do the exact same thing with alpha1.
        if (alpha1 == 0 or alpha1 == self._C) and (alpha1_new > 0 and alpha1_new < self._C):
            vector_alpha1_new = numpy.array([i1, E1])
            vector_alpha1_new = vector_alpha1_new.reshape((2, 1))
            self._errors = numpy.concatenate((self._errors, vector_alpha1_new), 1)


        if (alpha1 > 0 and alpha1 < self._C) and (alpha1_new == 0 or alpha1_new == self._C):
            l = 0
            position = 0
            while l < len(self._errors[0, :]):
                if self._errors[0, l] == i1:
                    position = l
                l += 1

            self._errors = numpy.delete(self._errors, position, 1)      



        #Then we update the error for each non bound point using the new values for alpha1 and alpha2.
        for i,error in enumerate(self._errors[1, :]):
            self._errors[1, i] = error + (alpha2_new - alpha2)*y2*self.kernel(self._data[i2], self._data[int(self._errors[0, i])]) + (alpha1_new - alpha1)*y1*self.kernel(self._data[i1], self._data[int(self._errors[0, i])]) - self._b + b_new


        #Storing the new values of alpha1 and alpha2:

        self._alphas[0, i1] = alpha1_new
        self._alphas[0, i2] = alpha2_new
        self._b = b_new

        print(self._errors)
        return 1




    def examineExample(self, i2):
        i2 = int(i2)
        y2 = self._label[i2]
        alpha2 = self._alphas[0, i2]

        if alpha2 > 0 and alpha2 < self._C:
            position = 0
            for i, elt in enumerate(self._errors[0, :]):
                if elt == i2:
                    position = i

            E2 = self._errors[1, position]
        else:
            E2 = self.evaluate(self._data[i2]) - y2

        r2 = E2*y2

        if (r2< -self._tol and alpha2 < self._C) or (r2 > self._tol and alpha2 > 0):

            n = numpy.shape(self._errors)[1]            
            if n > 1:   
                i1 = 0

                if E2 > 0:
                    min = self._errors[1, 0]
                    position = 0
                    for l, elt in enumerate(self._errors[1, :]):
                        if elt < min:
                            min = elt
                            position = l

                    i1 = self._errors[0, position]

                else:
                    max = self._errors[1, 0]
                    position = 0
                    for l, elt in enumerate(self._errors[1, :]):
                        if elt > max:
                            max = elt
                            position = l

                    i1 = self._errors[0, position]

                if self.update(i1, i2, E2):
                    return 1



            #loop over all non bound examples starting at a random point.
            list_index = [i for i in range(n)]
            numpy.random.shuffle(list_index)

            for i in list_index:
                i1 = self._errors[0, i]
                if self.update(i1, i2, E2):
                    return 1


            #Loop over all the training examples, starting at a random point.
            list_bound = [i for i in range(self._N) if not numpy.any(self._errors[0, :] == i)]
            numpy.random.shuffle(list_bound)

            for i in list_bound:
                i1 = i
                if self.update(i1, i2, E2):
                    return 1


        return 0




    def SMO(self):
        numChanged = 0
        examineAll = 1
        cpt = 1
        while(numChanged > 0 or examineAll):
            numChanged = 0

            if examineAll == 1:
                for i in range(self._N):
                    numChanged += self.examineExample(i)

            else:
                for i in self._errors[0, :]:
                    numChanged += self.examineExample(i)

            if examineAll == 1:
                examineAll = 0
            elif numChanged == 0:
                examineAll = 1

            cpt += 1    

















def load_training_data(a, b):
    train = gzip.open("train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "rb")
    labels = gzip.open("train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz", "rb")

    train.read(4)
    labels.read(4)

    number_images = train.read(4)
    number_images = struct.unpack(">I", number_images)[0]

    rows = train.read(4)
    rows = struct.unpack(">I", rows)[0]

    cols = train.read(4)
    cols = struct.unpack(">I", cols)[0]

    number_labels = labels.read(4)
    number_labels = struct.unpack(">I", number_labels)[0]

    image_list = []
    label_list = []
    if number_images != number_labels:
        raise Exception("The number of labels doesn't match with the number of images")
    else:
        for l in range(number_labels):
            if l % 1000 == 0:
                print("l:{}".format(l))

            mat = numpy.zeros((rows, cols), dtype = numpy.uint8)
            for i in range(rows):
                for j in range(cols):
                    pixel = train.read(1)
                    pixel = struct.unpack(">B", pixel)[0]
                    mat[i][j] = pixel


            image_list += [mat]
            lab = labels.read(1)
            lab = struct.unpack(">B", lab)[0]
            label_list += [lab]


    train.close()
    labels.close()


    i = 0
    index_a = []
    index_b = []
    while i < number_labels:
        if label_list[i] == a:
            index_a += [i]
        elif label_list[i] == b:
            index_b += [i]

        i += 1

    image_list = [m for i,m in enumerate(image_list) if (i in index_a) | (i in index_b)]
    mean = (a+b)/2
    label_list = [ numpy.sign(m - mean) for l,m in enumerate(label_list) if l in index_a+index_b]

    return ([image_list, label_list])





def load_test_data():
    test = gzip.open("t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "rb")
    labels = gzip.open("t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz", "rb")

    test.read(4)
    labels.read(4)

    number_images = test.read(4)
    number_images = struct.unpack(">I", number_images)[0]

    rows = test.read(4)
    rows = struct.unpack(">I", rows)[0]

    cols = test.read(4)
    cols = struct.unpack(">I", cols)[0]

    number_labels = labels.read(4)
    number_labels = struct.unpack(">I", number_labels)[0]

    image_list = []
    label_list = []
    if number_images != number_labels:
        raise Exception("The number of labels doesn't match with the number of images")
    else:
        for l in range(number_labels):
            if l % 1000 == 0:
                print("l:{}".format(l))

            mat = numpy.zeros((rows, cols), dtype = numpy.uint8)
            for i in range(rows):
                for j in range(cols):
                    pixel = test.read(1)
                    pixel = struct.unpack(">B", pixel)[0]
                    mat[i][j] = pixel


            image_list += [mat]
            lab = labels.read(1)
            lab = struct.unpack(">B", lab)[0]
            label_list += [lab]


    test.close()
    labels.close()

    return ([image_list, label_list])   

data = load_training_data(0, 7)
images_training = data[0]
labels_training = data[1]

svm = SVM(0.1, images_training[0:200], labels_training[0:200])

svm.SMO()




def view(image, label=""):
    print("Number : {}".format(label))
    pylab.imshow(image, cmap = pylab.cm.gray)
    pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

First, SMO is a fairly complicated algorithm - it is not one easy to debug in this kind of format.

Second, you are starting too high up in your testing. Some advice to help you debug your problems.

1) First, switch to using the linear kernel. Its much easier for you to compute the exact linear solution with another algorithm and compare what you are getting with the exact solution. This way its only the weight vectors and bias term. If you stay in the dual space, you'll have to compare all the coefficients and make sure things stay in the same order.

2) Start with a much simpler 2D problem where you know what the general solution should look like. You can then visualize the solution, and watch as it changes at each step - this can be a visual tool to help you find where something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing is you said this:

```
    b1 = E1 + y1*(alpha1_new - alpha1)*K11 + y2*(alpha2_new - alpha2)*K12 + self._b
    b2 = E2 + y1*(alpha1_new - alpha1)*K12 + y2*(alpha2_new - alpha2)*K22 + self._b
```

Basically you're just adding to b every time with this code. Your b's should look more like this:

```
    b1 = smo.b - E1 - y1 * (a1 - alpha1) * smo.K[i1, i1] - y2 * (a2 - alpha2) * smo.K[i1, i2]
    b2 = smo.b - E2 - y1 * (a1 - alpha1) * smo.K[i1, i2] - y2 * (a2 - alpha2) * smo.K[i2, i2]
```

This version is not perfect, but I recommend checking apex51's version on Github for pointers:
[SVM-and-sequential-minimal-optimization](https://github.com/apex51/SVM-and-sequential-minimal-optimization)

The mathematical basis in the notes are very strong (despite some minor discrepancies with Platt's paper) and the code is not perfect, but a good direction for you. I would also suggest looking at other, completed SMOs and trying to tweak that code to math your needs instead of writing from scratch.